# How do I read JSON file into a Dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to python so can anyone help me out?

i have the following contents in a json file (ie. file12.json)

```
{
    "TimeSeries": {
        "Row": [
            {
                "CLOSE": 41.85,
                "TIMESTAMP": "2016-09-22T00:00:00+00:00"
            },
            {
                "CLOSE": 41.37,
                "TIMESTAMP": "2016-09-23T00:00:00+00:00"
            },
            {
                "CLOSE": 40.88,
                "TIMESTAMP": "2016-09-26T00:00:00+00:00"
            },
            {
                "CLOSE": 40.98,
                "TIMESTAMP": "2016-09-27T00:00:00+00:00"
            },
            {
                "CLOSE": 44.33,
                "TIMESTAMP": "2016-12-21T00:00:00+00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a structured Dataframe, like this:

```
      CLOSE        TIMESTAMP
0     41.85        2016-09-22T00:00:00+00:00 
1     41.37        2016-09-23T00:00:00+00:00 
2     40.88        2016-09-26T00:00:00+00:00
3     40.98        2016-09-27T00:00:00+00:00
```

if i want to do the same with a csv, i simply use 'read_csv' but read_python produces a different output.

i've used this code...

```
file = pd.read_json('file12.json')
print file
```

...but the format isn't quite how i want it. i get the following:

```
TimeSeries
Row  [{u'CLOSE': 41.85, u'TIMESTAMP': u'2016-09-22T...
```

..ie. everything is simply on one row, rather than in a formatted table.

can anyone help me? please : - )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *Python for Data Analysis* by McKinney, he says

> How you convert a JSON  object or list of objects to a DataFrame or some other data structure for analysis will be up to you.

Try this (this untested code, ymmv)

```
import json
import pandas as pd
with open('file12.json') as json_data:
   obj = json.load(json_data)
   frame = pd.DataFrame(obj['TimeSeries']['Row'], columns=['CLOSE', 'TIMESTAMP'])
```

Answer (score 2):

The `rows` value part of the `json` string:

```
In [454]: txt1="""[
     ...:             {
     ...:                 "CLOSE": 41.85,
     ...:                 "TIMESTAMP": "2016-09-22T00:00:00+00:00"
     ...:             },
     ...:             {
     ...:                 "CLOSE": 41.37,
     ...:                 "TIMESTAMP": "2016-09-23T00:00:00+00:00"
     ...:             },
     ...:             {
     ...:                 "CLOSE": 40.88,
     ...:                 "TIMESTAMP": "2016-09-26T00:00:00+00:00"
     ...:             },
     ...:             {
     ...:                 "CLOSE": 40.98,
     ...:                 "TIMESTAMP": "2016-09-27T00:00:00+00:00"
     ...:             },
     ...:             {
     ...:                 "CLOSE": 44.33,
     ...:                 "TIMESTAMP": "2016-12-21T00:00:00+00:00"
     ...:             }
     ...:         ]"""
```

Parses as a list:

```
In [449]: json.loads(txt1)
Out[449]: 
[{'CLOSE': 41.85, 'TIMESTAMP': '2016-09-22T00:00:00+00:00'},
 {'CLOSE': 41.37, 'TIMESTAMP': '2016-09-23T00:00:00+00:00'},
 {'CLOSE': 40.88, 'TIMESTAMP': '2016-09-26T00:00:00+00:00'},
 {'CLOSE': 40.98, 'TIMESTAMP': '2016-09-27T00:00:00+00:00'},
 {'CLOSE': 44.33, 'TIMESTAMP': '2016-12-21T00:00:00+00:00'}]
```

and loads into pandas fine (interpreting the dates as `datetime64` types, the `convert_dates=True` default):

```
In [451]: df=pd.read_json(txt1)
In [452]: df
Out[452]: 
   CLOSE  TIMESTAMP
0  41.85 2016-09-22
1  41.37 2016-09-23
2  40.88 2016-09-26
3  40.98 2016-09-27
4  44.33 2016-12-21
In [453]: df.dtypes
Out[453]: 
CLOSE               float64
TIMESTAMP    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

But as `@Alex` shows you may have more control over the conversion by first parsing with `json.loads` and then loading a portion of that dictionary.  `obj['TimeSeries']['Row']` is this same list.

You could even take a `json` round trip to strip off the outer layers:

```
In [455]: dd = json.loads(txt)
In [456]: dd
Out[456]: 
{'TimeSeries': {'Row': [{'CLOSE': 41.85,
    'TIMESTAMP': '2016-09-22T00:00:00+00:00'},
   {'CLOSE': 41.37, 'TIMESTAMP': '2016-09-23T00:00:00+00:00'},
   {'CLOSE': 40.88, 'TIMESTAMP': '2016-09-26T00:00:00+00:00'},
   {'CLOSE': 40.98, 'TIMESTAMP': '2016-09-27T00:00:00+00:00'},
   {'CLOSE': 44.33, 'TIMESTAMP': '2016-12-21T00:00:00+00:00'}]}}
In [457]: pd.read_json(json.dumps(dd['TimeSeries']['Row']))
Out[457]: 
   CLOSE  TIMESTAMP
0  41.85 2016-09-22
1  41.37 2016-09-23
2  40.88 2016-09-26
3  40.98 2016-09-27
4  44.33 2016-12-21
```